# Solution for unmaskinig a service on read-only rootfs?

Tags: services, readonly

I have an embedded system with a read-only rootfs on which several services are masked.

The masking creates a symlink to /dev/null in /etc/systemd/system/.

The unmasking tries to remove the symlink but as the rootfs is RO, it fails successfully.

Is there a way to unmask said services without mounting rootfs in RW?

Answer (score 1):

You might try to create an [overlayfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt), re-mount it on /,  and tell systemd to reload all services (`systemctl daemon-reload`).

Comment: This way might be the right way. Unfortunately this change would not be trivial and for the moment I will not try it. I decided to just stop the services after boot.